# Temporarily Stop One Function Execution with setTimeOut() when a Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

I have an animation triggered by a scroll event, which makes a menu slide out of view. There is also a button that when clicked brings the menu back into view.

Because the menu can be closed by scrolling, when the user clicks the button to bring the menu in, if they scroll during this period of the animation, the menu disappears again without the animation completing.

I have put together a simplified version of the animation here http://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/evbzMQ

I need to temporarily prevent the scroll function working after the button is clicked, which I'm assuming would be best done with the setTimeout() method on the click function?  I've tried a number of things but can't seem to solve it/ get it to work.

Any help would be awesome.  For quick reference as well the code is below

JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // slide menu to left on scroll
    function hideOnScroll() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 1) {

          $('.menubox').css('left', '-25%');

      }

    }); 

  }

  hideOnScroll(); // call hideOnScroll function


  // click handler to bring menu back in
  $('.mybutton').on('click', function() {

      $('.menubox').css('left', '0%');

      var scrollPause = setTimeout(hideOnScroll, 2000)  // temporarily pause hideOnScroll function 

    });

}); //end of jQuery
```

CSS

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 200vh;}

.menubox {
  top: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.mybutton {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menubox">Menu Box</div>

<button class="mybutton">Click to bring back menu</button>
```

** Also please note I've simplified the animation for the sake of the forum, the actual animation function contains Greensock code, but I didn't want to include this in case it confused the issue. I can't therefore just use the .addClass() and .removeClass() or have a workaround that changes the given CSS or scrollTop() values.  I need to disable the hideOnScroll() function when the button is clicked for the duration of the click invoked animation - which in the examples is 2s. Thus I think the only way to achieve this is with the setTimeOut() method (i may be wrong on this).  But I can't get it to work.

Many thanks

Emily

Comment: I got your problem.. I implemented it and tried to solve it myself.. I think you didn't try the -webkit-transition and -moz-transition with the default transition property in css... if you use that then it will certainly finish its animation irrespective of any other action.

Comment: Hi Tirthraj, That's not the issue I'm trying to solve.  I put a basic animation in to illustrate what I need to do. What I want to happen is when the button is clicked to bring the menu back in the hideOnScroll() function is set to false for 2000ms. I have updated the CSS though so the animation shows on older browsers so thanks for that.

Comment: I understood your question after I posted that comment.. worked over it for some time.. and m still working on it.. Will soon share the solution..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply check the offset is complete.

```
function hideOnScroll() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 1) {        
     if( $('.menubox').offset().left == 0 ){
        $('.menubox').css('left', '-25%');          
      }   
   });
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJXGbr

Comment: Hi Weijian, I did say after the code in the notes above that I can't have a solution that changes the CSS or animation values themselves.  I need a solution that disables / pauses the actual scroll function from within the click function. The actual animation is a lot more intricate and uses Greensock.  I just need to find out how to pause / temporarily disable one function when a second one is clicked.

Comment: i'm not changing the css. I am only checking the css position.

Comment: This did work with Greensock after all because .offset() uses actual coordinates on the page.  I thought it only worked with the 'left' and 'right' properties etc, so wouldn't work on transforms (or transformX in particular).   Weijjan I owe you a huge apology and will mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

I have made a few changes in your `javascript`. Have a look

```
var animating = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function hideOnScroll() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 1 && !animating){
                    console.log("Hiding")
                    animating = true;
                    $('.menubox').animate({'left': '-25%'},2000,function(){
                        animating = false;
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        hideOnScroll();

        $('.mybutton').click(function() {
            var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
            animating = true;
            $('.menubox').animate({'left':'0%'},2000,function(){
                console.log("Finished Opening");
                animating = false;
            });
            console.log("Animating Open");
            var siId = setInterval(function(){
                if(animating){
                    console.log("Preventing Window Scrolling.");
                    $(window).scrollTop(pos);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Stopping setInterval");
                    animating = false;
                    clearInterval(siId);
                }
            },0);
        });

    });
```

This will stop your browser window from scrolling until your **Menu Open Animation** is finished.

Also I have removed the `transition`property from style.

Tested in Google Chrome.

Kindly inform me if i have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: No that isn't what I need. I need a statement within the click function so when the button is clicked, the hideOnScroll function is basically disabled for the duration of this animation, so if someone accidentally scrolls as the menu is sliding off screen, it doesn't slide back in midway through its exit from the screen.  I can't have a solution to this by changing the CSS or scroll top positioning, it must be controlled by a setTimeout() (or similar) actually disabling the hideOnScroll() function for the duration of the menu slide out animation after the button is clicked. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Also i've edited the notes at the bottom of the question which might make it clearer.  I may need to post a different question without any animation code present and just showing two functions with  a 'code goes here' in each of the code blocks to prevent confusion.

Comment: then can it be done with a global boolean variable that can be set true or false in the buttonClick function and can be checked if its animating or not in the hideOnScroll() function?

Comment: That's what i thought and have been trying.  If i can set the hideOnScroll() function to true globally and then set it to false within the click function in a setTimeOut()  I can't work out how to set a function call to true (I'm new to Javascript). I thought it would be something like:  var scrollCall = hideOnScroll();  scrollCall = true;  and then in the click function have setTimeOut(scrollCall = false, 2000);   but this doesn't work

Comment: Alright.. `window` object in javascript is yor actual browser window.. Moreover javascript is totally asynchronous at flow.. So the hideOnScroll function has a $(window).scroll() which again has a function where you have an if condition to check whether the scrollTop is > 1 or not.. Thats perfect.. Just add the global variable `animating` == false in that if condition..

Comment: doing that will obviously stop your hideOnScroll functions main code to execute...

Comment: Now just use a setInterval on button click where you can animate your menu slide open for 2000ms along with a callback function of completion where you can again set animating=false. You can put animate=true on button click and then button=false in the .animate() method's finish call back

Comment: ya and for same 2000 ms, you can write a setInterval function which will forcefully keep the scrollTop position exactly as it was when menu started sliding in.

Comment: as setInterval is a asynchronous flow function, we ll have to stop it externally as it won't finish along with the scope of its parent function.. so for that we use ànimating`variable again.. and do clearInterval() for forcefully stopping the setInterval() function exection.

Comment: And it is better to do such functions for lesser times.. I mean.. avoid using it for full-time if you can manage to use it for such 2 seconds gaps.. Cuz a lot of calls to setInterval functions at lesser period costs a lot of memory.. which might degrade your performance.